# Kendo UI Grid get Row Id in ClientTemplate

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a custom template for a column in a KendoUI Grid, and I need to get the Id of the row so I can pass it to a Javascript function. I should note that in the ClientTemplate I have some Url.Actions that can access the Id with "#=Id#" but that doesn't work with the function call for some reason.

```
"#if (hasLogFile(#Id#)) {#" +
    "<a role='button' class='btn btnAwesome' href='" + Url.Action("GetLogFile", "Run") + "/#=Id#' title='Log File'><i class='fa fa-file-text-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" +
"#} else {#" +
    "<a role='button' class='btn btnAwesome disabled-icon' title='Log File'><i class='fa fa-file-text-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" +
"#}#"
```

I have tried a myriad of things for the parameter to `hasLogFile();` (including `#=Id#`). It is possible to get some things passed into the function such as various jQuery objects or plain text. It's just a matter of getting the Id.

Comment: The template function scope is wrapped with a `with (data)`, that is why you should be able to access properties directly like `Id`, for example. But you still have the `data` object to mess with, so you could try pass it to your function, e.g. `hasLogFile(data)`. If the id is declared into the dataItem, it will be there.

Comment: This probably would work-->#if (hasLogFile(Id))...

Comment: Man, I could have SWORN I tried (hasLogFile(Id)) at some point with all the different iterations I used. If you want to put that in an answer, maybe with some detail as to why what I have in the question didn't work, I'll mark it as the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template data is wrapped in a way that you can reference it directly in your template code logic.

```
#if (hasLogFile(#Id#))…
```

becomes

```
#if (hasLogFile(Id))…
```